# Константный сигнал

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Вдруг отметил наличие в справке Qt такую запись, объявляющую сигнал константным:

```
class SomeClass : public QObject {
   Q_OBJECT

   signals:
      void someSignal() const;

   ...
};
```

В случае со слотами и методами наличие `const` понятно. А вот в случае с сигналом... Следует ли это интерпретировать как то, что слот-приёмник не должен изменять объект, отправивший сигнал?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Константные сигналы можно посылать из константных методов.

Comment: Хм, Вы правы. На ровном месте споткнулся, упустив очевидное. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Сигнал в Qt ничем не отличается от обычной функции(метода) поэтому к нему применимы все те модификаторы, что применимы к обычным функциям(методам). Как это интерпретировать? На мой взгляд никак не надо, т.к. `const` сигналы, на мой взгляд, явление из ряда вон выходящее. Да так делать можно, но абсолютно бессмысленно. Ни разу не встречал такого на практике, а кода на Qt я видел много разного.

Единственным смыслом подобной записи я вижу посылку сигнала из константного объекта, но это противоречит логике, т.к. неизменяемый объект ни о чём сигнализировать не должен.

P.S. Сигнал не может налагать никаких ограничений на слот. Это не его забота, что будет делаться на том конце.

Comment: Может быть это как-то связано с новым синтаксисом соединений, который был введён в пятой версии фреймворка? Методы могут связываться напрямую и на этапе компиляции производится проверка соответствия. Так-то конечно для соединений через строки (макросы SIGNAL() и SLOT()) получается бессмыслица.

Comment: Посмотрел я в гугле и нашёл несколько применений подобных сигналов - люди используют их для эмитирования сигнала из const методов. На мой взгляд там что-то не так с дизайном, но, тем не менее, люди используют.

Comment: Я впервый раз с таким столкнулся, ранее не приходило в голову вызывать сигналы из константных методов, но, похоже, это может быть полезно, если в теле метода сам объект не модифицируется, но производятся некие вычисления, результат которых можно передать на сторону.

Comment: Не знаю, на мой взгляд это неправильно, всё таки сигнал сообщает о некотором событии. В константном методе не может произойти никакого события, которое может видеть внешний мир, априори. Т.е. посылать сигнал из константного метода это какая-то проблема в архитектуре, скорее всего.